# Plurality - how to print up multiple winner if number of votes are equal?

Tags: c, cs50

Plurality program - The program takes input from user and prints the candidate with the most number of votes. I got two problems and I want that print_winner prints multiple winners in case of tie and it prints all the winners when everyone is tied? How do you suggest I do that?

If there are multiple winners with the same number of votes, how do you suggest I do that? While answering keep the words simple as I am new to programming and don't really get the difficult terms.

P.S I did the assignment, this is just a additional feature I want to add to it.

Thanks

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <stdbool.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct 
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) 
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2) 
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX) 
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) 
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) 
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name)) 
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name) 
{
    // TODO
    bool exist = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) 
    {
        //check if the typed in name is in the list of candidates
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0) 
        {
            candidates[i].votes += 1;
            exist = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    return exist;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void) 
{
    int most = candidates[0].votes;
    string winner = candidates[0].name;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++) 
    {
        if (most < candidates[i].votes) 
        {
            most = candidates[i].votes;
            winner = candidates[i].name;
        }
    }

    //printf("%d", most);
    printf("%s\n", winner);
    return;
}

/* Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void) {
  int most = candidates[0].votes;
  string winner = candidates[0].name;
  for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++) {
    if (most < candidates[i].votes) {
      most = candidates[i].votes;
    }

  }
  for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++) {
    if (candidates[j].votes == most) {
      winner = candidates[j].name;
      printf("%s", winner);
    }
  }
}*/
```

Comment: One way is to sort the `candidates` array, and print from the top in a loop until the vote-count changes.

Comment: I haven't been taught sorting yet so I guess I have to use a new loop but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/plurality/) program *must* handle "multiple winners", it's not an "additional feature":

> It is possible that the election could end in a tie if multiple
>   candidates each have the maximum number of votes. In that case, you
>   should output the names of each of the winning candidates, each on a
>   separate line.

Think about what you need to know to `print_winner`. You need to know *what* is the "most" votes, as program currently does in a loop. Additionally, you need to know *who* got that many votes. That would require another loop through the "candidates", printing each one that has the "most".

Comment: Yeah, it's additional as this program got me 89% in the result but the last condition didn't work and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: the commented `print_winner` function in the post edit look like things are moving in the right direction. Of course, it won't be graded if it's commented :)

Comment: check50 is working exactly right. I think _this_ `printf("%s", winner);` is not correct! Compare it to the other `print_winner` function. Run it in the console (creating a tie of course) and you should _see_ the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

To print multiple winners, you'll need a loop. Specifically, you could loop all over the candidates, and print out those that have a number of votes equal to `most`.

Comment: How do you do that? how should I change my code for it ?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You've already demonstrated you know how to loop over the candidates, and you've already demonstrated you know how to compare a candidate's votes against a variable. I've practically spelled out exactly what you need to do short of actually writing the code for you. What would you learn if I did that?! (And I get a downvote for my efforts? Despicable.) (Actually, I did code the solution for you, but I had the decency of hiding it in a HTML comment in my answer.)

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, I was asking as I tried it and it didn't work. Just look at this and tell me what I did wrong -

Comment: I didn't assume it was you. In fact, I didn't think it was you.

Comment: I added the code in the main one, would you please help me what I did wrong here?

Comment: I don't know but the check50 is giving me errors for this. I think there is something wrong here. Check again, the last part

Comment: Well, you should be printing a line feed after each name, but surely you noticed that?

Comment: I think, something is wrong with the check50 or my browser. I think the code is right too.

Answer (score 0):

your code does what you are trying todo but if you want make it more better try to cmpare if there are more candidates that have the same score as the most then have an array of winners and then print them all.